# Why is the ListBox's DesiredSize.Width always zero?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, uielement

I am creating a custom control in C#, and want to have a grid cell that contains a ListBox, which can be hidden or shown as desired. Hiding it is easy, I just set the Width to zero, however when I want to show it, I need to know the width that the ListBox would like to use.

I thought that DesiredSize.Width would give me this vale, but it's always zero, even after calling Measure(). Here is the code I'm using to show the ListBox...

```
_lb.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
_lb.Width = _lb.DesiredSize.Width;
```

Any ideas how I find the desired width?

Comment: I would recommend hiding it with: `_lb.Visible = false;` make it visible with: `_lb.Visible = true;`. How big should the listbox be, do you have a static value, or does it has to have the same width as another component?

Comment: I would like to set the actual width, as that way I can animate it when I show or hide it. I don't have a static value for the width, I want to get the width that the listbox would be if it had all the space it needed.

Comment: Is the listbox in a container, like a form or panel? If so, how is it called and what kind of control is it?

Comment: I created a class that inherits from UserControl, and overrode the OnInitialized event. In there, I created a Grid, which was set as the Content property of my control. I set up the grid and its child controls like you would in XAML, only I had to write the C# to do it instead. Does that help? Not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: Consider creating a [Custom Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements) that supports only a single child with a ScaleX dependency property.  It can measure its single child and give it a width equal to ScaleX*DesiredWidth (which is the same width it should provide to its owner container as its own DesiredWidth.)  If you then animate the ScaleX property, it will cause repeated layout updates that rescale the child appropriately up to its final desired width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `ListBox` is in the cell of a grid, give that grid column a name.  Then in code, you can access the `.ActualWidth` property of that grid column and use that value to set the width of your `ListBox`.

That assumes of course that the width of your grid column is not set to `Auto`, because that would still give you a `0` value.

```
_lb.Width = myGridColumn.ActualWidth
```

You might need to subtract a little bit from the column width to make your control fit nicely.

**EDIT**

One thing that I've found is that the `ListBox` must have items added to it before it will return anything other than `0` when it is measured.

```
string myItem = "Don't ask for a bath in Athabaska";
_lb.Items.Add(myItem);
_lb.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
double width = _lb.DesiredSize.Width;
```

As long as the `ListBox` has already been added to the window/usercontrol/grid, the above code returns a value of `227.53` for the `width` variable; using my defaults for font family and size.

If the `ListBox` has not been added to the window, or it doesn't have any items in it, it will return `0` for the `.DesiredSize.Width` property.

Also, if the `.Visibility` property is set to `Collapsed` instead of `Hidden`, the width will be 0.

Don't set the width to 0 when starting. Leave the width alone initially, set the `.Visibility` to `Hidden`. It will render to the needed width, but won't be shown. Then you can measure it and start playing around with the width.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the grid column's width is set to auto, so that when I animate the width of the listbox, the grid column resizes appropriately. I couldn't think of any other way of doing it. I couldn't animate the grid column itself, as I have a button at the top of the column that I use to show/hide the listbox, and I need to keep that visible. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you know the size of some of the content in the listbox, you can use that to determine the width of the listbox.

Comment: I have both set to Auto so that the contents of the listbox can determine width. How would I find the size of the contents? They are all just plain strings.

Comment: Just noticed your edit. The problem I have is that the listbox is hidden at first, and will only be visible when the user clicks the button. Therefore, when the code runs to measure the width, it will always return zero. The only way I can see round this is to have the listbox visible at first, which is not the desired behaviour. Any ideas?

Comment: You must be setting the `.Visibility` property to `Collapsed`.  If you do that, you will always get 0 width.  If you set it to `Hidden`, then you will be able to read the width properly.

Comment: I'm not setting the Visibility at all. All I do is create a Listbox, set the Width to zero and add a DataTemplate for the checkboxes that will be shown inside it. I set the Width to zero initially to ensure that it's hidden when the control first loads, which is probably the problem. I need to get hold of the width that the Lisbox would like to be, if it were allowed to have as much space as it wanted. Any ideas? Thx

Comment: Don't set the width to 0.  Leave the width alone initially, set the Visibility to Hidden.  It will render to the needed width, but won't be shown.  Then you can measure it and start playing around with the width.

Comment: Stwebob, thanks, that was exactly what I needed. It occurred to me that all of this code is running in the OnInitialized method of the control, so the user won't see anything until the method has ended. I was thinking I needed to set the Width to zero right from the start, to prevent the listbox from being shown briefly whilst the contents were measured. Your suggestion worked perfectly. Please can you update your main reply to explain this, and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.